# HOw to pair the bluetooth in two devices using NFC

Tags: bluetooth, nfc

I am trying to pair two devices

One is Google Nexus S  which has the applicaion running which reads the mac address written over the tag which is stuck on the other phone which is not Android one .

Now i am trying to pair the devices  as i tap on the other phone , my application reads the MAC address stored in the TAG  and  automatically creates the Bluetooth connection .

Everything is working fine but i am getting a pairing request or to match the keys on both the phones  which should not come.

Here is the Bluetooth Segment where the connection is happening

```
private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
    private String mSocketType;

    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device, boolean secure) {
        mmDevice = device;
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
        mSocketType = secure ? "Secure" : "Insecure";

        // Get a BluetoothSocket for a connection with the
        // given BluetoothDevice
        try {
            if (secure) {
                tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(
                        MY_UUID_SECURE);
            } else {
                tmp = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(
                        MY_UUID_INSECURE);

                Log.d("CHECK", "Sucessfully created insecure socket");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Socket Type: " + mSocketType + "create() failed", e);
        }

        mmSocket = tmp;

    }

    public void run() {
        Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectThread SocketType:" + mSocketType);
        setName("ConnectThread" + mSocketType);

        // Always cancel discovery because it will slow down a connection
        mAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        Log.d("CHECK", "Inside RUN");

        // Make a connection to the BluetoothSocket
        try {
            // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
            // successful connection or an exception

            Log.d("CHECK", "Trying to connect");

            mmSocket.connect();

            Log.d("CHECK", "Tried to connect");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Close the socket
            try {
                mmSocket.close();

                Log.d("CHECK", "Socket closed");

            } catch (IOException e2) {
                Log.e(TAG, "unable to close() " + mSocketType +
                        " socket during connection failure", e2);
            }

            Log.d("CHECK", "Connection failed");

            connectionFailed();
            return;
        }

        // Reset the ConnectThread because we're done
        synchronized (BluetoothChatService.this) {
            mConnectThread = null;
        }

        // Start the connected thread
        connected(mmSocket, mmDevice, mSocketType);

        Log.d("CHECK RESULT", "Sucessfully connected");

       // Toast.makeText(BluetoothChatService.ConnectThread.this, "Sucessfully connected" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect " + mSocketType + " socket failed", e);
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying for the insecure connection , but i dont know why it is asking for  the pairing keys in both the phones.

Comment: Hello, I need the same functionality to be develop. Please suggest me how you pair devices when they come closer and start transferring NDEF messages. Please reply me. Its urgent Please.

Answer (score 1):

Chek your bluetooth version because: 
(sic) "For Bluetooth 2.1 devices, the link key will be encrypted, as encryption is **mandatory**. For legacy devices (pre Bluetooth 2.1 devices) the link key will be not be encrypted."

Comment: Thanks for your reply .. but i am using command  tmp = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(
                        MY_UUID_INSECURE);
 and the explanation of the command says that it will go ahead and make the connection bypassing the encryption link required.

Comment: Are you sure? My answer was copied from the explanation of the online documentation. Check it again please.